# Grouping of attributes in entities (Core Data)

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data

I've created my database but need to group certain attributes together for example,

**Entity:** `Human`

**Attributes:** `Nose` `ears` `mouth` `fingers` `toes`

**Grouped attributes:**

`Face`(`nose` `ears` `mouth`)

`Hand`(`fingers`)

`Foot`(`toes`)

Is there any way to group the attributes so that I can just show all `Face` attributes? Instead of listing out `nose`, `ears`, `mouth`

obviously with a small database listing out the attributes is fine but when the database gets bigger this can get complicated fast.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: When you say "show" or "listing out", do you mean within the design tool or within a running program?  (IOW, how are you showing them?)

Comment: Just in general, querying a subset of the data instead of the data cleanly. I've asked a new question based off of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703852/setting-up-core-data-for-2-dimensional-table

Comment: A general comment: Thinking of Core Data as a database is a problematic approach whether you're dealing with structure or queries.  It's an object persistence tool, so keeping an object-oriented focus is the most effective use of it.  (The underlying database is an implementation detail that should be treated like the bit pattern that makes up the letter 'A'.  That is, usually ignored.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't group the attributes. 
What you could possibly do would be creating entity Human with relationships to other entities that describe your groups. So you would have entity Face with attributes: nose, ears, mouth etc and then you would create a relationship between those two entities. But my point is that this is totally unnecessary and pointless because you would have a one-to-one relationship between your entities - a human can have only one face and each face belongs only to one human.
I think that only thing you should do is to create some way of logging that suits you.

Comment: Thanks, I've asked a new question based off of this question. Maybe you'll be able to shed some light on how to best setup my database:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703852/setting-up-core-data-for-2-dimensional-table