# Setting up Core Data for 2 dimensional table

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data, multidimensional-array

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id | infinitive | ind pre je | ind pre tu |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | aimer      | aime       | aimes      |
|  2 | aller      | vais       | vas        |
|  3 | courir     | cours      | cours      |
|  4 | servir     | sers       | sers       |
|  5 | mourir     | meurs      | meurs      |
|  6 | dormir     | dors       | dors       |
|  7 | sentir     | sens       | sens       |
|  8 | vêtir      | vêts       | vêts       |
|  9 | fuir       | fuis       | fuis       |
| 10 | tenir      | tiens      | tiens      |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

I'm working on a French conjugation app that tests users on their conjugation by displaying a verb in infinitive form and the tense required. The goal is for the user to input the conjugated form of that verb and press a button to check their answer. If the answer is correct, a new verb will be generated, etc.

I have a 2-dimensional data set, please see table above for a small-scale version of the data. I'm trying to work out how best to setup my database in core data because it doesn't clearly fit in the 1-dimensional entity-attribute model that core data has.

Ideally I would like to be able to allow users to select which tenses they would like to be tested on and also categorising the verbs - regular form, irregular form, common verbs, etc.

Should I make each conjugated verb an entity that has a relationship with it's pronoun which has a relationship with its tense, which in turn has a relationship with its infinitive verb form?

eg.:

`ate`- `I` - `Past tense` - `to eat`

(conjugated form)- (pronoun)- (tense) - (infinitive form)

Comment: I dont know French, so I dont really understand, but then, u could create an Entity with attributes - id , infinitive, ind pre je, and ind pre tu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend storing two entities: verbs and conjugations.  Verbs has a one-to-many relationship with conjugations.

So `Verb` would have the following properties: `infinitive`, `isRegular` `conjugations`(relationship)

And each conjugation would have: `verb` (relationship), `tense`, `pronoun`, `conjugation`.

It does not make sense to have an entity for pronouns or tenses as they are set things (there are always exactly 3 tenses) and do not increase or decrease with the user's data.  So it makes more sense for these values to be enums.